# Check for a state of a service in Windows using C via Windows API / function

Tags: c, service

Hi recently I used the windows system call

```
popen ("sc query winmgmt | find STATE","r");
```

to get the state of the windows management instrumentation
but I've been told to use a windows function / API instead

Is this possible? with C only?

Comment: @Joe Not a complete solution, though. I'll add an example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know how to use the windows API, the function you're looking for is [QueryServiceStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A simple example of using `QueryServiceStatusEx`:

```
// Services (MSDN):
//   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141(v=vs.85).aspx

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *serviceName = "winmgmt";

  SC_HANDLE sch = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
  if (sch == NULL){
    printf("OpenSCManager failed\n");
    return 1;
  }

  SC_HANDLE svc = OpenService(sch, serviceName, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
  if (svc == NULL){
    printf("OpenService failed\n");
    return 1;
  }

  SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS stat;
  DWORD needed = 0;
  BOOL ret = QueryServiceStatusEx(svc, SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,
                                  (BYTE*)&stat, sizeof stat, &needed);
  if (ret == 0){
    printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (stat.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING){
    printf("%s is running\n", serviceName);
  }else{
    printf("%s is NOT running\n", serviceName);
  }

  CloseServiceHandle(svc);
  CloseServiceHandle(sch);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will this work on C?

I'm trying to see if I can make it work without making shared libraries

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you mean can you make it work without ultimately using a `dll` then no. But why do you feel that's important? And why can't you just do it the way you show in your question?